# Remove Ubuntu 12.04.4 from secondary drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, hard-drive, format

I am a novice and need help to solve the following.

1. My computer.

   - Intel i5-4440 processor,
   - Intel DB85FL motherboard,
   - Western Digital WDC WD5000AAKX-6 , 500 GB, primary disk with Ubuntu
     13.10,64bit, whole disk.
   - Seagate ST3500418AS , 500 GB, secondary with 12.04.4,64bit, whole
     disk.
   - Samsung SyncMaster 943 and so on.
2. In BIOS, the boot priority is as follows.

   - DVD drive
   - WD HDD
   - Seagate HDD
   - USB
   - Internet
3. On booting the system, Ubuntu displays the option to boot from

   - Ubuntu,
   - Advanced options for Ubuntu 13.10,
   - Ubuntu 12.04.4,
   - Advanced options for Ubuntu 12.04.4,and System Setup

I want to remove everything on the secondary Seagate ST3500418AS, 500 GB, with 12.04.4, to use it as my backup drive. But without affecting anything from Western Digital WDC WD5000AAKX-6 , 500 GB, primary disk with Ubuntu 13.10. I have nearly 208GB data on this.

Please advice me.

Comment: In theory, you should be able to either remove the secondary drive or delete the partition on the secondary drive, and then run `sudo update-grub`. The Ubuntu 12.04 entries should disappear.

Comment: @Stormvirux thanks for beautiful format of my questions.

Comment: @saiarcot895 Thanks for your suggestion. Could I have a step-by-step tutorial, please.

Comment: I posted the tutorial as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In Ubuntu 13.10 (on the drive you want to keep), open up GParted.
2. Check to see which drive is listed as which. My guess is that the Western Digital drive will be listed as /dev/sda, and the Samsung drive will be listed as /dev/sdb. If it's the other way around (or if you have more drives listed), change the next step appropriately.
3. Switch to the /dev/sdb drive (the Samsung drive) using the drop-down in the top-right corner.
4. You should see your Ubuntu 12.04 partition. Right-click on the partition and remove the partition.
5. Apply the changes. GParted might see that the boot configuration might be affected, and so might automatically do the next step, but just in case (there's no harm in doing it twice)...
6. Open up Terminal and run `sudo update-grub`.
7. When you reboot, you should see that only Ubuntu 13.10 has the menu entries present. At this point, you can remove/repurpose the Samsung hard drive.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It worked, but I have to perform the step 5 twice. The consecutive problem of using the drive was new to me. This solved the issue --- > http://itsfoss.com/set-write-permission-ext4-partition-ubuntu-linux/